# httpd 2.4 mod_rewrite sends alias directory to browser url

Tags: bash, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

We have httpd 2.4.29, with custom *.conf and .htaccess.

`myUrl.com/old/folder/alpha.sh`, the page displays the `alpha.sh` as expected

`myUrl.com/old/folder/alpha`, sends a redirect to the browser so the url changes to `myUrl.com/home/my/new/folder/www/alpha.sh` with a `503`

`myUrl.com/old/folder/beta`, (beta does not exist), keeps the url as expected and generates a forbidden `You don't have permission to access /beta.sh on this server.`

What is wrong with the configs below that causes the execution directory to be returned with a 503 when a *.sh file exists?

NB:if we change the type of rewrite to `RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.html [L]` and cgi-script is not used, then the rewrite works as expected.

myUrl.conf

```
AddHandler cgi-script .sh
LoadModule cgid_module libexec/mod_cgid.so
LoadModule rewrite_module libexec/mod_rewrite.so

Alias "/old/folder" "/home/my/new/folder/www"
<Directory "/home/my/new/folder/www">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    Options +ExecCGI
</Directory>
```

/home/my/new/folder/www/.htaccess

```
DirectoryIndex index.html
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /$1.sh [L]
```

/home/my/new/folder/www/alpha.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
# get today's date
OUTPUT="$(date)"
# You must add following two lines before
# outputting data to the web browser from shell
# script
echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo ""
echo "<html><head><title>Demo</title></head><body>"
echo "Today is $OUTPUT <br>"
echo "Current directory is $(pwd) <br>"
echo "Shell Script name is $0"
echo "</body></html>"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteBase /old/folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.sh -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /$1.sh [L]
```

The `RewriteBase` should set to `/old/folder` (same as the alias definition), and it would be a good practice to check if the `.sh` file exists with this `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.sh -f`

See also: [Apache Virtual Host with Alias](https://serverfault.com/questions/347476/apache-virtual-host-with-alias)

Comment: still the same result.

Comment: if permission deny error, you need to grant the `execute` permission

Comment: Hi Ben, please see the info in the post, when requesting the file with `alpha.sh` it works as expected. Only when the rewrite to add an extension is activated does the problem exist. So not a permission error. Thanks Art

Comment: you have alias definition, you might need to set `RewriteBase /old/folder`